# ImportError: cannot import name 'prefetch_relations'

Tags: python, django

It seems I have an error while trying to run my local django server.
Whenever I type "python manage.py runserver" this error pops up:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x042E7C48>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
        six.reraise(*_exception)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
        app_config.import_models(all_models)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 104, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\notify\models.py", line 14, in <module>
        from .utils import prefetch_relations
    ImportError: cannot import name 'prefetch_relations'
```

Is there any way I can fix this problem?

P.S
The project was working just fine 1 week ago

Comment: it's a complete website. with more than 20k lines of code. I can't figure out what triggered it...

Comment: @GalFridman Can you upload your code to github (plus requirements file)?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

For some reason I had to reinstall the django-notify-x package.

Afterwards all worked just fine!